# getting xml data always in extjs ajax responce with c# svc file

Tags: c#, json, extjs, svc

I have a Extjs ajax request where i'm making request to svc (C#) - it always returns xml data .

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax'
    , url: '/Service/TestService.svc/getUserList'
    ,actionMethods: {
        read: 'POST'
    }
    ,reader: {
        type: 'json'
        ,root: 'records'
        ,totalProperty: 'count'
    }
    ,writer: {
        type: 'json'
    }
    ,extraParams: {
        mode: 'list'
    }
}
```

How i can get response in json format. [image]